# Sending array of Json data along with image file with ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send array of json data and image file with ajax but i can only get image file and not getting json data and i can see json data sent properly in fiddler though.In action method, collection parameter for json data  says count=0. How can i get array of json data?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetData", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, new { @id = "form_", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("imagefile", null, new { @type="file"})
    @Html.Hidden("formdata", null, new { @data_formdatajson = "" }))
    @Html.TextBox("submit", null, new { @id = "button", @value = "upload", @type = "submit"})
}

    var DataClass = {
            data1: data1value,
            data2: data2value
        }

dataArray=[];
dataArray.push(DataClass);
dataArrayJson = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
$('#formdata’).data("formdatajson ", dataArrayJson);

           $('#form_').on('submit', function (e) {
                var dataArray_ = $('#formdata ').data("formdatajson");
                var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                formdata.append('formdata', dataArray_);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/GetData/Home/',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                            },
                            error: function () { },
                        });
                    });
public class DataClass
{
     public string data1 { get; set; }
        public string data2 { get; set; }
}

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetData(IEnumerable<DataClass> formdata, HttpPostedFileBase imagefile)
        {
                    return Json(new { success = true },  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: You should use `formdata.append('formdata', dataArray_);` instead of `formdata.append('dataarray', dataArray_);`

Comment: nope this didnt help:(

Comment: Have you tried setting `contentType` to `"application/json"` instead of to `false`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil yes i tried...i got error 500.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem...I dont know why but Asp.Mvc gets json data and add an empty element to outside of json array for no reason.I used request.form to get json and i eliminated this additional data by using substring.Now it works.